Not able to view GeoWebCache seed and reseed logs
I am using GeoServer 2.20.0
I wanted to deep dive into reseeding issue however logs do not show any information regarding seeding.
I am looking for logs in geoserver/data_dir/logs/geoserver.log file
I have tried editing configuration logging.xml and log4j.properties. After restarting the geoserver and seeding tiles I still see no logs.
Is there any other way to check logs?
